# Фильтрация одинаковых записей в таблице

Tags: sql, база-данных, firebird

Как корректно сделать выборку из таблицы, фильтруя одинаковые записи по столбцу `Name` и выводя все остальные столбцы?
Пример таблицы:

```
ID | Name  | Phone | LastVisit  
1  | ФИО_1 | 12345 | 01.01.2018  
2  | ФИО_1 |       | 07.04.2018  
3  | ФИО_2 | 54321 | 17.02.2018
```

Запрос `GROUP BY` должен вывести

```
ID | Name  | Phone | LastVisit
1  | ФИО_1 | 12345 | 01.01.2018  
3  | ФИО_2 | 54321 | 17.02.2018
```

Например, `SELECT Name FROM ExampleTable GROUP BY Name;` убирает одинаковые записи, но выводит один столбец, т.к. в выборке указан один столбец.
А хочется что-то типа такого `SELECT * FROM ExampleTable GROUP BY Name;`, хотя этот запрос неправильный, т.е. нужна выборка всех столбцов, но группировка по столбцу `Name`.

Comment: Вам надо более чётко определить алгоритм выбора одной записи из группы записей с одинаковым Name. Так, чтобы по нему для любого мыслимого набора можно было однозначно ткнуть пальцем в ту запись, которая останется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Firebird версии 3.0+ можно воспользоваться [оконными функциями](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Phone, LastVisit
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, ORDER BY id, name) AS rn
    FROM ExampleTable AS t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Максимально приближено к тому, что вы сформулировали:

```
select name, max (Phone) Phone, max (LastVisit) LasVisit
from table1
group by name
```

Выводит уникальный `name` и одно из множества других значений.

И со всем уважением советую вам немного почитать что-нибудь по теории реляционных БД.

Т. к. ваш вопрос, увы, некорректно сформулирован.